# Communicate with a TCP Server via strings?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tcp, client

I have a server running that runs on TCP/IP. It reads strings and responds with strings. I just wondered if I can just connect via Flash to my server and get some answers from it. My second idea was:

```
var socket: Socket = new Socket("192.168.0.100", 4847);

socket.writeObject("hello");
var answer: String = socket.readObject();

trace(answer);
```

Connection is established successfully. But I'm not sure how I send and receive strings now.

---

**Update:**

- `socket.writeUTFBytes("hello\r\n");` seems to work for sending
- how to read ? `socket.readUTF()` ?

  - I **don't know** how long the answer might be, it can be short or very long
- how about *end of line* ? It is important for my server since that's how messages are separated. Do I have to send eol via `"\r\n"` ?
- **Update 2:** [This seems to work well](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how your server handles the requests and repsonses. For sending and receiving strings use the readUTFBytes and writeUTFBytes.

If you want to use the functions writeObject and readObject your server must know how to handle the AMF serialization. You can find libraries for different languages on this wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format and implement AMF on the server . If you are working on a larger project I would personally recommend that.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it now. `readUTFBytes` and `writeUTFBytes` is **exactly** what I needed for the communication.